# Perl, regular expression, matching exactly 2 spaces does not work

Tags: regex, perl

Working on the parser for STA/SSTA timing reports. The following cases of "Arrival Time" occurrence are possible:

```
  Arrival Time                3373.000
- Arrival Time                          638.700 | 100.404
                             Arrival Time Report
```

The goal is to match cases 1st and 2nd, but ignore 3rd case.

I tried two matching patterns in my Perl code:

1) `if (m/^-?\s{1,2}Arrival\sTime/)  { ($STA_DATA{$file}{$path}{Arrival_Time}) = m/\sArrival\sTime\s+(.*)\s+$/ }`

2) `if (m/^-\sArrival\sTime/ || m/^\s{1,2}Arrival\sTime/)  { ($STA_DATA{$file}{$path}{Arrival_Time}) = m/\sArrival\sTime\s+(.*)\s+$/ }`

Both of them pick up the 3rd case as well. I do not understand why.
I defined specifically one or two space characters `\s{1,2}`, no more than that. As the 3rd line contains more than two whitespace character it should not match the pattern. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure that the third case has space characters at the beginning of the line, and not maybe tab characters? Because they are matched by `\s` as well

Comment: Why would it matter if tabs match unless there are only one or two tabs?

Comment: I do not know for sure if some of the whitespace characters are tabs. Judging by the size only, there seems to be no tabs in there. Besides I counted 29 whitespace characters, which is >2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tabs can have variable length. The OP's input example could even have only a single tab before `Arrival Time Report`, depending on their terminal settings or text editor settings.

Comment: Searching for a certain number of whitespaces seems fragile...why not just ignore lines that match `Arrival Time Report`?

Comment: Yes, finally, I have fixed it by adding another regexp part to it `if (m/^-?\s{1,2}Arrival\sTime/ && !m/Arrival\sTime\sReport/)  { ... }`. Still, that is not the reason form my post here. I do not need a solution. I would like to understand why `\s{1,2}` does not work...

Comment: @BorisL.: That is fine, but you must post your real data so that we can help. What you show us has no tabs at all, and is useless. Stack Overflow will properly preserve tabs as well as spaces, so you have pasted something that is different from the original data. Many editors will reduce tabs to the equivalent number of spaces, so you should publish the data file on line so that we can help you

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot about `s/->//g; s/\s\S+\s[v\^]\s//g; s/\s+/ /g;` Now I understand why it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have published is not the same as you used in your test.

This program checks *both* of the regex patterns against the data copied directly from an edit of your original post. Neither pattern matches any of the lines in your data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my (%STA_DATA, $file, $path);

while ( <DATA> ) {

    if ( /^-?\s{1,2}Arrival\sTime/ )  {
        say 'match1';
        $STA_DATA{$file}{$path}{Arrival_Time} = m/\sArrival\sTime\s+(.*)\s+$/
    }

    if ( /^-\sArrival\sTime/ or m/^\s{1,2}Arrival\sTime/ ) {
        say 'match2';
        $STA_DATA{$file}{$path}{Arrival_Time} = m/\sArrival\sTime\s+(.*)\s+$/
    }
}

__DATA__
      Arrival Time                3373.000
    - Arrival Time                          638.700 | 100.404
                                 Arrival Time Report
```

Comment: That is strange, I copy pasted from the original files. I'll have a look at it now...

Comment: You should remove the four leading spaces from the input data that were used to signify a code block in Markdown. When you do that, the first two lines match and the third doesn't, which is still proof that the data in the question doesn't match what the OP is actually using; either that, or they're doing something wrong in the code they haven't shown.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You are right, it is indeed something else in the code that I completely forgot about.  `s/->//g; s/\s\S+\s[v\^]\s//g; s/\s+/ /g;`  Of course it does not work. Thank you for the hint and sorry for keeping everyone busy for nothing... :)

Comment: @BorisL. No worries, these things happen. In the future, you should make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Other users should be able to copy and paste the code and input from your question verbatim, run it on their own systems, and see the same behavior that you see. A lot of times, you'll actually discover the solution to your own problem in the course of making an MCVE!

Comment: @BorisL.: That is fine, but the primary worth of any question on Stack Overflow is that it can be useful to others with a similar problem. Accordingly we still need to see your real data and the code before and after the “fix”

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future issues.

Comment: @Borodin: I'll try to post an answer to my question (i.e. explain the mistake I made) tomorrow, when I fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible workaround you can try:

```
if (m/^-?\s{1,2}Arrival\sTime\s{2,}/) { ($STA_DATA{$file}{$path}{Arrival_Time}) = m/\sArrival\sTime\s+(.*)\s+$/ }
```

You can match the string "Arrival Time   " with two or more spaces after it, ruling out the string "Arrival Time Report"

Comment: I will leave this answer up until you find the root cause of why so many regexes which should be working are not.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot about `s/->//g; s/\s\S+\s[v\^]\s//g; s/\s+/ /g;` Now I understand why it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm your regex is inside a loop reading the input line by line ?

In case `$_` contains the whole text your observation would be expected because you anchored the extracting regex to the end of the text by using a `$`.

Comment: Yes, regexp is in the while loop, hence reading line by line. ` open(IN,'<',"$file_name.rpt") or die "Can't open input file: $!";
 while (<IN>) {`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot about `s/->//g; s/\s\S+\s[v\^]\s//g; s/\s+/ /g;` Now I understand why it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

It should help to replace spaces in your data with Unicode U+2423 *OPEN BOX* that is commonly used to signify a space using a visible character.

```
␣␣␣␣␣␣Arrival␣Time␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣3373.000
␣␣␣␣-␣Arrival␣Time␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣638.700␣|␣100.404
␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣Arrival␣Time␣Report␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣
```

Comment: In nedit replacing 'space' character by 'dot' character results in following: `.............................Arrival.Time.Report...........................`, while 'tab' character by 'dot' character does not change the line. Hence, they are all spaces, no tabs in there.

Comment: @BorisL.: Yes. I'm not sure what you're saying here except that you agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but still, the question is not how to fix it, but why it does not work.

Comment: @BorisL.: No one can tell you unless you provide your real data. Does [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) help? I'm unsure why I'm still trying to help you when you have been told repeatedly why we can't tell the problem unless you expose the details properly

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot about `s/->//g; s/\s\S+\s[v\^]\s//g; s/\s+/ /g;` Now I understand why it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

As rightfully requested by Borodin, for the learning of others I'm gong to explain the mistake I have done and show the solution.

The mistake that I have done is following:

I wrongly assumed that my matching pattern is being applied on the text as seen in the .rpt file.
Three cases (relevant for my matching pattern) that can occur in such a file are following:

```
  Arrival Time                3373.000
- Arrival Time                          638.700 | 100.404
                             Arrival Time Report
```

But, I have forgotten that somewhere in the code I have implemented following line:

```
s/->//g; s/\s\S+\s[v\^]\s//g; s/\s+/ /g;
```

It is namely the last substitution in this series of substitutions that changes the original text into:

```
 Arrival Time 3373.000
- Arrival Time 638.700 | 100.404
 Arrival Time Report
```

There for my matching patterns (that are presented in the question above) did not work.

Knowing this, the solution is simple. I have adjusted matching pattern as follows:

```
if (m/^\-?\sArrival\sTime\s\d+/) { ($STA_DATA{$file}{$path}{Arrival_Time}) = m/\sArrival\sTime\s(.*)\s?$/ }
```

I appreciate all the help and feedback received, and I truly sorry for wasting everyone's time with this ill defined problem.